# loop in SQL server program with Table

Tags: sql-server, loops, join, foreach, sql-server-2012

My expected result is quit difficult to explain so here i have shown sample data.

**SourceTable**: (I have alphabets in `HeadNo` column)

```
HeadNo   |   Start   |   End
---------+-----------+----------
   AA    |   AA0000  | AA9999
   AB    |   AB0000  | AB9999
   AC    |   AC0000  | AC9999
   AD    |   AD0000  | AD9999
    --------------------
    --------------------
    ------- so on ------
   ZZ    |   ZZ0000  | ZZ9999
```

From this source table, I want to create kind of loop result, where each `HeadNo` will give return `10000` result for each, starts from `0000` to `9999`.

**Result should look like**:

```
HeadNo   |   Actual Code
---------+---------------
   AA    |   AA0000
   AA    |   AB0001
   AA    |   AC0002
   AA    |   AD0003
    --------------------
    --------------------
    ------- so on ------
   AA    |   AA9998
   AA    |   AA9999
```

like wise for each `HeadNo`

```
   ZZ    |   ZZ0000
   ZZ    |   ZZ0001
   ZZ    |   ZZ0002
   ZZ    |   ZZ0003
    --------------------
    --------------------
    ------- so on ------
   ZZ    |   ZZ9999
```

I want to merge and insert into one separate single table.

Comment: Will the value of `Actual Code` always be in the format `AA0000`?

Comment: @Cid: ya i change my output first row,

Comment: @Larnu: yes, format will be always with 2 head alphabets and 4 digits.. like AA0000 to ZZ9999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** every row requires the values 0-9999 then you simply need to CROSS JOIN to a tally table:

```
WITH N AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
         CROSS JOIN N N4 --10000
    )
SELECT YT.HeadNo,
       YT.HeadNo + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(4),T.I),4) AS ActualCode
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS JOIN Tally T;
```

If, however, you have actual start and end ranges per `HeadNo` (like the example below), you'll need to use a little more logic in  the `JOIN`:

```
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('AA','AA0000','AA9999'),
                ('AB','AB0000','AB5000'), --Guesssing this is more realistic
                ('AC','AC1000','AC8000'), 
                ('AD','AD0000','AD0100'),
                ('ZZ','ZZ0000','ZZ9999')) V(HeadNo, HeadStart, HeadEnd)),
N AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1
         CROSS JOIN N N2 --100
         CROSS JOIN N N3 --1000
         CROSS JOIN N N4 --10000
    )
SELECT V.HeadNo,
       V.HeadNo + RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(4),T.I),4) AS ActualCode
FROM VTE V
     JOIN Tally T ON T.I BETWEEN STUFF(V.HeadStart,1,2,'') AND STUFF(V.HeadEnd,1,2,'')
ORDER BY V.HeadNo,
         ActualCode;
```

The second examples **assumes** that `HeadNo` will always have the format `AA0000`; if it doesn't then we're missing important information that should be  included in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your above query worked as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. I used recursive CTE to obtain numebrs from 0 to 9999 and then `cross join`ed to your `HeadNo` column:

```
;with cte as (
  select 0 n
  union all 
  select n + 1 from cte
  where n < 9999
)

select HeadNo, HeadNo + right('0000' + cast(n as varchar(4)), 4) from MyTable
cross join cte option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: This won't give the expected results. The OP wants strings of the format `'AA0000'` The `int` value `0` cast to a `varchar(4)` is the value `'0'`, giving the final result `'AA0'`. Also, A CTE like this is a hidden form of RBAR; a tally table would avoid the require for `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` and likely provide a performance benefit.

Comment: @Michał Turczyn use Order by to get the expected result.